# Are there any web based IMAP clients out there

Tags: email, email-client

I would love to be able to stop using application based email clients and move completely to the web for my email. The problem is the webmail clients for my job suck compared to Gmail. Is there something out there that would act as an imap client for multiple accounts that are a little more intuitive than the standard webmail clients out there?

Comment: My apologies. Did not know that. Will keep that in mind down the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first consideration, since it sounds like you want to migrate your work email to a web solution, you should consider whether your company has policies against making internal emails available outside the corporate network.  If you regularly communicate sensitive information or trade secrets, you have to accepts that by outsourcing your mail infrastructure (even if it's just for your own mailbox), you are making it easier to access those secrets by people outside the company.

That aside, my university uses [RoundCube](http://roundcube.net/) for email.  While not as good as GMail, it's not bad either.  It looks like it supports IMAP access.

Comment: "you should consider whether your company has policies against making internal emails available outside the corporate network"

This betrays a bit of a misunderstanding of the term 'client' - while web is capable of communicating over `http`, `https` and `ws` pretty much exclusively (nonstandard protocol support non-withstanding), with any existing service exposing http api calls or a local mapping service for those IMAP to calls to e.g. WS would be capable of functioning entirely in browser only, so this is not really a concern.

Comment: Something like https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap + https://github.com/jmapio/jmap-js + https://github.com/jmapio/jmap-demo-webmail would do the trick. And a bunch of coding.